# Laptop keyboard backlight ribbon cable broken

Tags: keyboard, laptop, backlight

I've accidentally broke my laptop keyboard backlight ribbon cable when disassembling my laptop. I want to solder it back by patching with copper wires or maybe copper plates.

My question is, it is a 4-pin connector, i exposed the end of the ribbon with sand paper but there is only 2 lanes of copper instead of 4. Do I just need to solder them back or it should be 4 ? I found the diagram of the keyboard light and attached some photos of my cable.

[image: Keyboard Backlight diagram]

[image: Keyboard cable]

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ...... all you have to do is to reconnect the two lanes of copper

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad expression. The header pins are 4 lanes, aren't the copper lanes should be four as well? That's my question. Thanks!

Comment: why would you think that there should be 4 lanes? .... the person that designed the cable decided that there should be two pins for each lane .... maybe for a reliability reason .... most likely to prevent the cable from unplugging too easily

Comment: the bottom line is that you have to somehow restore the circuit .... that means that you have to reconnect two signal paths ..... i fail to understand why you think that you have to modify the original circuit by somehow splitting the two lanes into four

Comment: Because I thought that there should be one lane for each pin as each pin has their own purpose. Anyway, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schematic shows a connector with 4 pins and 2 grounding tabs. It shoes pin 1 and 2 are ground, pin 3 and 4 power. The FPC has two conductors, 2 pins per conductor to increase the amount of copper that is carrying the power and return path of ground, likely to reduce resistance and power loss. It's exactly how it's supposed to be.

If you broke the fpc, simply repairing it by reconnecting each conductor to where it should be connected  is the only method.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit does not need 4 lanes. Soldering 2 lanes of the cable to the circuit will be perfectly fine.